# Getting label size correctly

Tags: pyqgis

I tried different functions for getting the label size. They all return only the size of the first line - `label.sizeWithUnits().height()`, `label.boundingRect().height()` etc.

How to get label size with all the contained text?

```
for labeldata in places.places:
    label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
    print(labeldata["name"])
    label.setText(labeldata["name"])
    #label.setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 30))
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial"))
    text_format.setSize(30)
    label.setTextFormat(text_format)
    label.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(50,y, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    label.adjustSizeToText()
    #y += label.sizeWithUnits().height()
    y += label.boundingRect().height()
    layout.addLayoutItem(label)
```

Above code does not put the labels under each others, instead it moves them down by one line height. `places.places` contains list of dicts containing the string item `"name"`, for the place names. I cannot manage to put them each below the previous one - it moves y position only by line height, not by height of all lines. If function to ask, how many lines is a label, exists, this would help also.

Comment: Can you give an example of some label text (fake if your data are sensitive) and an image of how you expect it to look?

Comment: Some of the places: places = [{'name': 'Centre Residencial de Primera Acollida Sant Gervasi'}, {'name': 'Centre d’Estades Breus (CUESB)'}, {'name': 'La Terrasseta'}, {'name': 'Barcelona Actua'}, {'name': 'Església Exèrcit de Salvació'}]. They are positioned exactly as the script does (y, initially, is 50) - current script, which moves every item label.boundingRect().height() pixels down related to previous label, will have the text positioned on top of the second line of previous label, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The function that works best for me is sizeForText()

I have drafted the following code

```
labels_to_add = ["This is a label with a single line", 
    "This is a label with 2 lines\nThis is a label with 2 lines",
    "This is a label with 3 lines\nThis is a label with 3 lines\nThis is a label with 3 lines"]
layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName("a")
page_collection = layout.pageCollection()
count_page = page_collection.pageCount()
current_page = 0

while(current_page < count_page):
    starting_value_of_y = 10
    y = starting_value_of_y
    offset_per_label = 10
    for text in labels_to_add:
        label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
        label.setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 30))
        label.setText(text)
        label.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(50,y, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
        label.adjustSizeToText()
        layout.addLayoutItem(label)
        y += (label.marginY() * 2) + offset_per_label + label.sizeForText().height()
    current_page += 1
```

I took the liberty to add an offset between the labels,
the result produced is the following

[image]

with the "extra" offset_per_label set to 0, the result produced is the following

[image]